# Why the amount of points for those badges is so odd?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, badges, meta, reopen

As you can see in the images below, the amount for the "Reviewer" badge for *Suggested Edits* is quite low in comparison with the *Reopen Votes*. Even with the amount in all-time being so far from each one.

is this logic for the purpose to make it difficult at the first and going easy after the amount of reviews go up? If so, why not make a fixed number or even the reverse of this?

[image: Suggested Edits]
[image: Reopen votes]

Comment: You can vote outside the review queues - and before they ever existed in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your blue circles are in the wrong place. You have circled the *total* reviews from *all users*.

I have drawn red circles around the values you should be considering.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the 82 and the 16 are mine =X the top users with the score are 876 and 26

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, Now I understood =X

Comment: This is clearly the best answer on the entire network simply due to the abundance of freehand circles.

Comment: @StrixVaria I count 16 freehand circles. Interested if there's even an MSO post with more.

Answer (score 3):

The badges *are* a fixed number, you get a badge after 1 review, 250 reviews and 1000 reviews. The "all time" reviews figure circled includes everybody's reviews, this is a total score for the whole site.

- Custodian - Completed at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type.
- Reviewer - Completed at least 250 review tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type.
- Steward - Completed at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type

Comment: I took @fredley answer because of the images, but +1 great answer

Comment: See, told you so!

Comment: blatant favoritism shown towards them circles.

Comment: @pixel You have much to learn, if you still don't understand the dark powers that freehand circles hold in meta.